# PyQt5:How to communicate between two subwindows?

Tags: python, pyqt

How to update the combobox in subwindow1 from subwindow2.The following code should be working fine but it doesnot update the combobox and doesnot show any errors at the line

```
 AddressBook().updatestock(name)
```

in the add function.It looks like it creates an instance of the AddressBook.If so how can i rectify it.

```
import os
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class menudemo(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(menudemo, self).__init__(parent)

    self.pilot_widget=AddInventory()
    self.drop_widget=AddressBook()

    self.centralWidget=QMdiArea(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    self.sub1=QMdiSubWindow()
    self.sub1.setWidget(self.drop_widget)
    self.centralWidget.addSubWindow(self.sub1)
    self.sub1.show()

    self.sub2=QMdiSubWindow()
    self.sub2.setWidget(self.pilot_widget)
    self.centralWidget.addSubWindow(self.sub2)
    self.sub2.show()
    self.setWindowTitle("menu demo")
    self.showMaximized()

class AddInventory(QWidget):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(AddInventory, self).__init__(parent)
    self.statement=""
    self.nameLabel = QLabel("Item:")
    self.name=QLineEdit()
    self.addButton = QPushButton("&Add")
    self.addButton.setDefault(True)
    self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameLabel, 0, 0)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.name,0,1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.addButton, 0, 3)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setWindowTitle(" Address Book")
    self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())
 def add(self,text):
    name=self.name.text()
    AddressBook().updatestock(name)
    self.name.clear()

class AddressBook(QWidget):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(AddressBook, self).__init__(parent)


    nameLabel2 = QLabel("Item:")
    self.itemstock=QComboBox(self)
    self.itemstock.activated[str].connect(self.updatestock)
    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(nameLabel2, 0, 0)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.itemstock, 0, 1)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setWindowTitle("Simple Address Book")
    self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

 def updatestock(self,name):
    print(name)
    self.itemstock.addItem(name)

def main():
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 ex = menudemo()
 ex.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because you're just creating a new instance of `AddressBook`, you call a method on it.

It is not linked to `self.drop_widget`

You have to link both widgets using the constructor. You do this in the `main`

```
self.pilot_widget=AddInventory()
self.drop_widget=AddressBook()
```

I would do:

```
self.drop_widget=AddressBook()
self.pilot_widget=AddInventory(self.drop_widget)
```

and change `AddInventory` class parameters

```
class AddInventory(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, drop_widget, parent=None):
      self.drop_widget = drop_widget  # now it is linked in your class as a member
```

now, in `add`:

```
 def add(self,text):
    name=self.name.text()
    self.drop_widget.updatestock(name)
    self.name.clear()
```

Comment: thanks....works like charm...what can be done if there were many windows and change need to be reflected in all the windows.